# Laravel - Trabajar con fechas en formato dd/mm/yyyy y yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

tengo un template con blade donde recojo la fecha de un datepicker de boostrap de esta forma

```
    //datepicker
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
        });
    });
```

El modelo lo tengo de esta forma

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Consumption extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['user_id','date_fueling'];

    protected $dates = ['date_fueling'];

}
```

El problema lo tengo en el controlador , ya que tengo el campo en la BD date_fueling es de tipo **date**

He probado a recojer el valor de esta forma y me da error me dice que el formato no es válido

```
        $input['date_fueling'] = $request->get('date_fueling');
        $consumption = Consumption::create($input);
```

Así que he probado a transformarlo con carbon pero me da el mismo error

```
$input['date_fueling'] = Carbon::parse($request->get('date_fueling'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Como me recomendáis hacerlo?

Gracias

Comment: laravel 5 o 7? exceso de etiquetas...

Comment: laravel 7 estoy usando

Comment: Prueba con esta guia, al parecer si es el controlador el problema. - > https://styde.net/formulario-con-datepicker-en-laravel/

Comment: Y cuál es el error que obtienes?

Comment: Agrega el mensaje de error que obtienes

Comment: Lo he solucionado con esto...pero lo veo un poco "lioso"

Comment: $input['date_fueling'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->get('date_fueling'))->format('Y-m-d');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución más efectiva es cambiar el tipo de dato de la columna `date_fueling` del tipo `date` al tipo `dateTime`, por medio de una migración de Laravel:

```js
Schema::table('consumptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dateTime('date_fueling')->change();
});
```

Y para guardar el dato en la base de datos, solamente hay que hacer lo siguiente:

```
$object_model->fuel_consumption = Carbon::parse($request->date_fueling);
$object_model->save();
```

Y es todo, ya no tendrás necesidad de hacer algo tan complicado como lo tienes actualmente.

Comment: gracias @Noob Dev, mi idea era como solo necesito la fecha usar un campo "date"